# What is a good way to implement semantic versioning with Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, semantic-versioning, jenkins-blueocean

I just started setting up and playing around with jenkins recently. I'm wondering if there is a good way to set up some kind of automatic semantic versioning.

Specifically I would like jenkins to automatically increas the patch version untill I manually increase the minor or major version.

I'm using jenkins with the blue ocean interface and am using [this Jenkinsfile](https://github.com/usbpc/usbTeleport/blob/36e5110aee53a9c3e573a424ee8eae829abff613/Jenkinsfile) to build my project.

I'm takling about semantic versioning as defined [here](https://semver.org/).

Or is my idea of automating this not really the right thing to do and should I do it manually?

Comment: Hi, i faced the same problem and in my opinion semantic versioning should be handled manually as the developer is the one who knows wether he is committing a new feature or a bug. Code review should address correct versioning issues. Perhaps adding metadata to the number could be done automatically. I haven't found any good post on this topic so far.